# Decimal to hex for int64 in c

Tags: c

Why this code does not work ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
  printf("%X", 1327644190303473294);
}
```

I am getting o/p `5f264e8e`

but expected o/p is `126cbd5b5f264e8e` as given by below php script

```
<?php
  echo dechex(1327644190303473294);
?>
```

Comment: The question is: why are you using `printf` with a C++ program? :)

Comment: I have written this as an example. I have doing sprint on c char array buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portable way to do this is to

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

And to do:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <inttypes.h>  // for PRIX64 macro (and INT64_C macro from stdint.h)

int main(void) 
{
    printf("The value is %"PRIX64"\n", INT64_C(1327644190303473294));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I agree that INT64_C() is better.

Comment: `INT64_C()` is not a C99 standard macro.  It's not in my `inttypes.h` for instance (Mac OS X 10.7).  However, `(int64_t)1327644190303473294` will work just as well and is C99 standard.

Comment: Aologies, I was looking in the wrong header for the `INTn_C()` macros

Comment: @JeremyP: Yes, it is in stdint.h, which must be included by inttypes.h. I also use Mac OS X 10.7, FWIW.

Answer (score 6):

> format '%X' expects type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'long int'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%lX",1327644190303473294);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
126CBD5B5F264E8E
```

Comment: `long` may not be 64-bit (it isn't on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

`%X` is for `int`, which is usually 32-bit. The required incantation for a 64-bit number is platform-dependent. On the Mac, it's `%qX`.

Comment: `q` is deprecated on OS X 10.7 Lion, [printf(3)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/printf.3.html).

Comment: @Mats any platform independent solution ?

Comment: @Vivek:  Rudy's answer is pretty close to platform independent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different format specifier to indicate that your integer is 64 bits wide. As it stands, your code interprets the input as a 32 bit integer.

In MSVC this would be `%I64x`, on some platforms it would be `%lx` and there are indeed other specifiers.

In summary, you need to choose a specifier appropriate for your particular toolset.

Comment: `long` may not be 64-bit (it isn't on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

for uint64_t, you can try as follow:

```
uint64_t val = 1327644190303473294;
printf("val: 0x%llx\n", val);
```

Comment: `warning: format ‘%llx’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t’`